# How to draw Pareto chart

Tags: statistics, matlab

I have a data set that contains five attributes. All the attributes have the same number of counts. I want to know how can i construct a Pareto chart for the data. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you will have four bars of equal height, giving a rather uninteresting [Pareto chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart).

Comment: Rather than having counts on the y axis what else can we have on the y axis of the Pareto chart